# System back button not working in Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

I have to implement **Navigation Component** in a Fragment(**MainFragment**) and all other fragment inside the navigation component.

> I simply want to handle system back press on Navigation that's implemented in MainFragment

I initially added my MainFragment to MainActivity like

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val bundle = bundleOf("sourceType" to 0)
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<MainFragment>(R.id.fragment_container_view, args = bundle)
            }
        }
```

Now In **MainFragment** I have added **NavHost**(Navigation Component) . There I have two fragments **CategoryFragment**(start Destination) **GalleryFragment**. Now when I move from CategoryFragment to GalleryFragment using direction.

On pressing back it should move to CategoryFragment but it will kill my app instead

**Why is it so?**.

As far as my understanding it should move to the previous fragment

**MainFragment.kt**

```
class MainFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_main){
    private val mViewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
    private val mBinding: FragmentMainBinding by viewBinding()
    
    lateinit var mainSearchNavHostFragment: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        /*val onBackPressCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if(mainSearchNavHostFragment.navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.galleryFragment){
                    findNavController().popBackStack()
                }else findNavController().navigateUp()
            }
        }
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this,onBackPressCallback)*/
    }

    private fun searchGallery(categoryToSearch:String){
        if(::mainSearchNavHostFragment.isInitialized){
            mainSearchNavHostFragment.navController.navigate(R.id.galleryFragment, Bundle().apply {
                putString("categoryType",categoryToSearch)
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        mainSearchNavHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
    }
}
```

Or whether I have to implement OnBackPressedCallback in each fragment , AFAIK it should be done by default . I am doing something wrong .

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use "supportFragmentManager.commit" or "childFragmentManager.findFragmentById" when using Navigation Component and ViewBinding.

Comment: supportFragmentManager  is written in Activity to inflate MainFragment (Where NavHost is implemented).

Comment: @TaimoorKhan That's not the right way. You can just set startDestination in your navigation xml file.

Comment: I have to pass bundle parameter at start . That can't be done via navigation.xml

Comment: @TaimoorKhan You can define the argument in navigation.xml and give it a default value.

Comment: What if I want to change it at run time. I mean I am creating this as a gallery app for any app . Any project pass SourceType(Pixabay or Unsplash) then it will work

Comment: @TaimoorKhan In runtime you can pass a bundle to navigate method similar to what you've done. navController.navigate(R.id.nav_destination, bundleOf("sourceType" to 1000))

Comment: In order to provide startDestination bundle, We have to inflate navgraph dynamically. We can't provide bundle to the starting destination without inflating navgraph at runtime